# Better way to store the data that is needed in many places in the app

Tags: java, android

This question has been asked many times before, but I haven't found a proper solution yet after researching about it for few days.

I'm fetching data (quite large data around 1 Mb) from server in **splash activity** which is going to be used in many places in the app, so I need to store this data in some place so that it is easily accessible from other activities. I can think of many ways to achieve this

**1) Storing the data in application class**

Seems to be simple and straight forward approach. But there is a risk of app crashing due to `NullPointerException`, when app goes to background android system kills the application class and recreates it. Since the data was loaded to application class in splash activity, recreation of application class destroys the data.
[this article](http://www.developerphil.com/dont-store-data-in-the-application-object/) explains this issue in detail.

**2) Storing the data in disk, and reading again from disk in each activity**

Even though this approach eliminates the possibility of `NullPointerException`, it seems to be less efficient as we need to read files from disk in each activity.

**3) Storing the data in preferences**

This might be good approach for fewer data (key value pairs), but since I have to store bit large data this isn't feasible for me.

**4) Storing the data in database**

The data is quite not structured and i don't think storing it in database is solution to my requirement. Also the data is needed only for the duration from - app launch till the app is killed, since new data is loaded in splash activity each time app is opened.I would go for disk caching rather than database.

**5) Passing the data through intent**

Intent `putExtras` method also has size limitation, so we cannot pass large data.

I am wondering if anyone has come across this problem and found an efficient solution for this? I prefer going with first approach so it would be helpful if you can suggest a way to recreate the data in application class if it is destroyed.

Thanks.

Comment: Store data in `SQLite` what's problem with that?

Comment: There's new technology for saving data called database

Comment: What about storing it in a singleton class?

Comment: @M D @RandykaYudhistira The data is quite not structured and i don't think storing it in database is solution to my requirement. Also the data is needed only for the duration from - app launch till the app is killed. I would be prfer singleton approach, but only problem in singleton is that data is destroyed when app goes to background.

Comment: @avk Same problem as in storing the data in application class. The data will be destroyed when app goes to background.

Comment: @AbhishekV But if your data is large then SQLite is best option and you can structure and singlton is also not a gud option. But i still confused **Also the data is needed only for the duration from - app launch till the app is killed** what your question exactly?

Comment: @MD I meant I will be loading new data in splash activity each time app is opened. So the data is needed only for that particular life time of the application. Database might be suitable for storing persistent data which is  needed for longer duration of time.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of data, but from personal experience I would recommend storing the data in a **SQLite database**. SQLite is both thread-safe and quick to access and most data will fit into a relational database structure. Also, it will not require you to keep your data in the RAM, which could lead to your app being terminated for memory on weaker phones.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Singleton

```
public class Singleton {

    private static class SingletonHolder {
        private static Singleton mInstance = new Singleton();
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return SingletonHolder.mInstance;
    }

    private Singleton() {

    }

}
```

The above is an example of a thread safe singleton pattern with minimal overhead. In your case you will initialize the data in the constructor and access it through the singleton object. This guarantees that if the object is garbage collected (your app is killed by the Android OS), your data will be reloaded once your app is restarted, because the constructor will run again.

I would recommend that you add an interface as argument to `getInstance()`, with a methods like `onLoadData()` and `onDataLoaded()`, so you can display a loading indicator in your UI when the data is being reloaded. In order to not go about implementing the display-loading code in every `Activity` and / or `Fragment`, you can use a base class that provides the loading indicator display.

Comment: Do NOT use a singleton for storing 1MB of data! Unless you want your app to be terminated constantly on low-end devices.

Comment: To me, the question is vague in it's description of the actual type of data that's going to be stored, as well as how often it is accessed. My answer assumes that the 1 MB of data is required to be in memory at all times. 1 MB is not a lot of memory, even on low end devices, besides if the app is terminated, the data will be reloaded when it is restarted.